# Is roslyn a reasonable substitute for reflection related tasks?

Tags: reflection, roslyn

Have a question, never used roslyn before so i'm wondering about maybe experimenting it in a task that i would normally use reflection.

I'm given an external dll, i need to go over some classes in that dll and extract some metadata on them.
Like for example, the class name, property names and types and such.

I would normally use reflection to do it. Should be a super simple task.
But i've been told that this can be achieved using roslyn.

Can it? From what i'm seeing, Roslyn can parse a class but i need to give it the code that represents this calss as text. How would i get the code as text in an already complied code?

Is that even a reasonable scenario to use roslyn? Does it worth the effort?

Thanx!

Answer (score 4):

If all you need is information that's already easily available via reflection, then Roslyn is likely to make it much harder. There's quite a lot of setup required, which can be error-prone and brittle in the face of new releases, in my experience.

I would typically use reflection for anything where the starting point is an *assembly*. When the starting point is *source code*, that's when it makes more sense to use Roslyn.

When Roslyn is the right tool for the job, it's amazing - but it doesn't sound like that's the case here.

Answer (score 1):

When you using Roslyn, you have lexical info and symbolic info.
The lexical info won't help you, you must use the symbolic info, for that, you must have `compilation` and you can create it for compiled code.

With the compilation, you indeed can achieve types info but not runtime info. Anyway, using reflection for this is much straight forward.

When your mission is related to tree transverse or syntax rewriting, Roslyn is perfect, but for metadata info, it's the wrong usage.

It depends on your specific needs but maybe there are other "tools" that more suitable for your task (e.g. cecil or dnlib)